# Systemd timer and conditional service interaction

Tags: timer, systemd

I've got a conditional systemd service `foo.service` with condition `ConditionDirectoryNotEmpty=/tmp/foo`. It's a one-shot service to empty `/tmp/foo`.

This works correctly in isolation. If I start the service when `/tmp/foo` holds a file, the service runs and the file is removed. If not, the service is skipped. Either way, it runs in less than a second.

The problem arises when I try to start this service from an associated timer. The timer gets stuck in a broken state. `systemctl list-timers` shows that `foo.timer` has a `NEXT` entry in the past (!) and it fired one millisecond ago. Indeed, it appears to be continously firing. That's of course not the timer setting:

```
[Timer]
OnUnitActiveSec=
OnUnitActiveSec=60s
Persistent=true
```

60 seconds is a lot more than one minute. The empty `OnUnitActiveSec=` line is intentional; it should clear any existing timer period.

Why is the timer going berserk? Why is it firing so often, why is the next time to fire in the past? Most importantly, how do I run a service once a minute, but only if needed?

`systemd` version 215, on Debian 8 (Armbian 5.30)

Answer (score 2):

There are apparently two parts to this question, each of which individually does not solve the problem.

The timer should have `OnBootSec=...` which defines the first time that the service runs after boot. The `OnUnitActiveSec=60s` only defines the interval **between** timer events, and does not tell you when the timer first fires.

Secondly, [it appears](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/systemd-service-runs-twice/16528) that the service you're starting should be **disabled**. That doesn't make much sense to me either, but remember that a disabled service can still be started explicitly by `systemctl start foo.service`. It looks like an "enabled service" is merely one that is started automatically when its conditions are met (typically at boot). That's not how this one-shot service should behave; it should just run in response to the timer.

The start of `foo.service` can still be controlled by conditions in the service itself; this is still the case when the service start request is initiated by a timer.